# re:Enter formula when cell become blank/empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to create an GoogleSheet Script but I'm no expert so i can't figure it out my self. (can't even declare the sheet where i want this event to happen)

Here's my current code which is very far from what I want to happen

```
function minsTriggers() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
.timeBased()
.everyMinutes(1)
.create();
function refresh() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('')
.setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("Link","Table!A2:E5000")');};}
```

What I want to happen is when Cell b3 on Sheetname "Imported Data" become blank(its becoming blank due to importrange error) Cell b2 has to re:enter its formula(Like refreshing the formula in the cell")

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want a bit? is it to empty the value on `B2` every minute?

Comment: @AMolina it was originally coded with "Importrange" but from time to time its having a importrange internal error and when it has an internal error the b3 will become empty so to refresh the code I want "B2" to delete its formula then re:enter it. this way it will refresh the importrange. This is my goal. I hope you get it

Comment: I think I got it, you want to, every once in a while, put the formula in `B2` in case it's empty, correct?

Comment: @AMolina In case the "Importrage Internal error Appear" on "B2" hehe

Comment: Got it, and you'd know the error is there because `B3` is blank, correct?

Comment: Hey @BlinkStark just wanted to check if the problem had been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function check(){
  var formula = '=IMPORTRANGE("Link","Table!A2:E5000")';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(ss.getRange("B3").getValue() == "")
    ss.getRange("B2").clear().setFormula(formula);
}
```

This will check if `B3` is blank, and if so, it will set the formula in `B2`. As for the trigger, I would suggest you set a time-based installable trigger ([instructions here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)). You could also use an `onEdit`, but changes made by scripts don't trigger it, there are plenty of options, but it all depends on how you access the sheet.